# Let $|G| = 20$ and $G$ has only two elements of order $4$. Then $G$ is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, sylow-theory

> Let $|G| = 20$ and $G$ has only two elements of order $4$. Then $ G$ is cyclic.

I was trying to prove this assertion and I was given some hints also. But firstly I don't know about sylow theorems yet.

> Definition: Let $G$ be a group and $|G|=p^n.q$, where $(p,q)=1$. Then every subgroup of order $p^n$ is called sylow $p$-subgroup.
>
> Theorem (Sylow's III):
> If $N_p$ is the number of sylow $p$- subgroup of a finite group $G$ ($|G|= p^n.q$, where $(p,q)=1$). Then $N_p = 1+kp$, where $k>=0$ and $N_p$ divide $q$. $( N_p\mid q)$.
>
> Theorem: If there exists only one sylow $p$-subgroup for each prime $p$, which divides $|G|$. Then $G$ is direct product of those sylow $p$-subgroup.

**My Attempt :** Using these theorems I got to the point to prove that there's only one sylow $5$-subgroup and it is of order $5$.

Again, for sylow $2$-subgroups : $$ N_2 = (1+2k)\mid 5$$
Therefore,
$k = 0$ or, $2$

If $k=2$, then there's only $5$ subgroups of order 4 say $H_1,H_2,H_3,H_4,H_5$.
Now, given that there's only two elements of order 4.
Let, $|a|=4=|b|$
Then, $\langle a\rangle=\langle b\rangle $ otherwise resulting two more distinct elements $a^3,b^3$ of order 4.

Now here I came to a dead end. I know that if I can prove that $k=2$ results in contradiction then my proof is done. But I can't find any ways from here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I mean, you are basically done. If $k = 2$, then how many different elements of order $4$ are contained in $H_1$ or $H_2$?

Comment: @Marktmeister here I'm confused actually..all the $H_i$ are of order 4 but is it necessary to contain any order $4$ element in them? I mean obviously one of these $H_i$ will have those two order $4$ elements..but can I say that the other ones should have any order $4$ element?

Comment: @Pritam Yes.  Another basic fact about Sylow subgroups is that all Sylow subgroups of a given order within a group are conjugate to each other, which in particular means that they're isomorphic to each other.  So if any one of them has an element of order $4$, all of them must.

Comment: Other $H_i$s can be of the form ${ e, a, b, ab}$ where each non-identity element is of order 2. Can't it be?

Comment: @RobertShore oh, I had no clue... thanks now I'm done.

Comment: No, because a subgroup of that form can't be isomorphic to a subgroup with an element of order $4$, so it can't be conjugate to such a subgroup, as required by another of Sylow's theorems.

Comment: Hm, since you say that you don't know all of Sylow's Theorems, let me propose the following. Let $H_1 = \langle h_1 \rangle$. Let $g \in G$ be an element of order $5$. If $g$ and $h_1$ commute, then $G$ is Abelian, hence cyclic (since it contains an element of order $4$). If $g$ and $h_1$ do not commute, then $g^{-1}h_1g \notin H_1$ (why?), and thus you get another element of order $4$.

Comment: @Marktmeister I think it doesn't belong to $H_1$ because $|g^{-1}h_1g| = 4$. But how can I prove that $g^{-1}h_1g \ne h_1^3$ ?

Comment: @Pritam If $g^{-1}h_1g = h_1^3$, then $g^{-1}(h_1gh_1^{-1}) = h_1^2$. Now use that $\langle g \rangle$ is normal.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$ be an element of order $4$. Then $\langle a \rangle$ is a subgroup of order $4$ so it is one of the Sylow $2$-subgroup.

Without loss of generality, assume that $H_1=\langle a \rangle$. Note that $H_1$ has two distinct elements of order $4$, namely $a$ and $a^3$.

Note that $H_1\cap H_2$ is a subgroup of $H_1$.
Case 1: $H_1\cap H_2=1$. Since $H_2$ is also a cyclic subgroup of order $4$, there exists an element of order $4$ in $H_2$ which is not $a$ or $a^3$; a contradiction.

Case 2: $H_1\cap H_2=H_1$. Then $H_1=H_1\cap H_2\leq H_2$. Since $|H_1|=|H_2|$, we have $H_1=H_2$; a contradiction.

Case 3: $H_1\cap H_2=\{1,a^2\}$. Since $H_2$ is cyclic group of order $4$, it has only one element of order $2$, so again there exists some element of order $4$ in $H_2$ which is not $a$ or $a^3$; a contradiction.

Comment: instead of 3 cases couldn't it be done in one case such as : Since every $H_i$ is cyclic therefore they must contain a order $4$ element. If it is different from $a,b$ then already a contradiction and if not then one of $a,b$ is in $H_i$s other than $H_1$ $ \implies H_1 = H_i, \forall i$

Comment: @Pritam Yes your arguments work too.

Answer (score 0):

The existence of an element of order  $4$ means the Sylow-$2$ subgroups are cyclic.   Furthermore there's only one,  since otherwise we have more than two elements of order  $4$.

For the Sylow-$5$ subgroup, it's normal,  by the fact that the number of them is $1\pmod5$ and divides $4$.

We're done, since then $G $ is the direct  product $C_4\times C_5\cong C_{20} $ .

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ has only two elements of order $4$, than it has only one (cyclic) subgroup of order $4$, *hence normal*, say $H$. On the other hand, by Cauchy,  it has a (cyclic) subgroup of order $5$, which is unique by counting reason, *hence normal*,  say $K$. Since, in addition, $H\cap K=\{1\}$ and $G=HK$, we get $G\cong H\times K\cong$ $C_4\times C_5\cong$ $C_{20}$.